# Ubuntu Eclipse Icon Creation

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I was tring to install eclipse on ubuntu. What I did:
I unzipped the tar archive of eclipse.
I tried to start eclipse from the command line - like this - ./eclipse. It works.
But then I tried to create a desktop icon with: 
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop --create-new.
In a new icon I showed the path to the eclipse executable which I could launch from the command line. But then eclipse does not start stating:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/artem/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

And also I get a message in the terminal (at some stage it appeared):

```
(gnome-desktop-item-edit:8998): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.DSV8LW': No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x32 and eclipse Juno.

PS. PATH variable points at jdk/bin and JAVA_HOME - to the jdk folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make launch "icon" by using symlink:
`ln -s [TARGET DIRECTORY OR FILE] [SHORTCUT]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with Graphic interface

Right click on eclipse. Choose `"Make link"`. You will get a short cut in the folder. Copy the shortcut to the Desktop. Done :)

P.s:
By the way, if you don't like default icon of the shortcut. They look all the same and ugly. Just right click on the shortcut and click on the small icon on the left, then choose an image icon which you like (E.g: Eclipse icon).